# Is it even mathematically possible to calculate fit images on the paper with the same spaces between them?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, photo, aspect-ratio

I have to create algorithm (in JavaScript) to calculate size and X,Y position of the images inside paper without cropping them to another aspect ratio. This is not that difficult, but between photos can be space with variable width - given with the input, same in X and Y axis. This final collage should be placed on the paper by the longer edge. Is it even possible? 
[image: collage with grid space between images]

Comment: Have a look at masonry

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the answer. I know that plugin, but I have designed layouts and masonry IMO can only do this automatically without respecting or prescribing layouts.

Comment: What is allowed? Scaling that preserves aspect ratio? If you want constant space between the photos then it's not always possible.

Comment: @PaulHankin yes scaling is possible. Everything that preserves aspect ratio is possible, and the layout should be preserved too.So far I do not think, there is a solution for this that maintain constant spaces :(

Comment: If you have 3 square images, you can't fit them in a square with constant spacing. So it's not possible in general.

Comment: @PaulHankin yes, that is true, but the collage itself may not fill whole paper, just fit the paper with longer edge of the collage.

Comment: Then a solution always exists -- just use 1 row or column along the longer edge.

Comment: I found a solution to not calculate it by myself, but use Cassowary solver.